# How to use ng-hide/ng-show or ng-style with changing youtube videos

Tags: angularjs

I have a view that displays youtube videos. I have 4 screenshots below the embedded player that I would like to use as to select the video to be played. I have used ng-hide/show and ng-style/ng-if in similar situations but I cannot get it to work with this setup.
[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RDIfzAU2U6c1r5wle7w9?p=preview)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/1hGkTqOYxEk?rel=0&autoplay=0" style="width:100%;height:500px"></iframe>

    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/Z2elVurPk5s?rel=0&autoplay=0" style="width:100%;height:500px" ng-hide="true"></iframe>

    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/2ruHn_9FokI?rel=0&autoplay=0" style="width:100%;height:500px" ng-hide="true"></iframe>

    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/D5zoVoL1_LU?rel=0&autoplay=0" style="width:100%;height:500px" ng-hide="true"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h4>1st Video (initial video)</h4>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/140x150" ng-click=""/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h4>2nd Video</h4>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/140x150"  ng-click=""/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h4>3rd video</h4>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/140x150"  ng-click=""/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h4>4th video</h4>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/140x150"  ng-click=""/>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain a bit more about what do you want to achieve and were is the issue? (btw. I have tried to add a console.log inside the main controller and nothing pops up)

Comment: k, give me a second. thanks

Comment: I want the user to be able to watch 4 different videos. I only want to show one video player at a time. The thumbnail photos below the player is how I want the user to select which video to watch. I want to use ng-hide/show to make it work. Click on the 2nd video thumbnail and it appears, etc..  The issue is I cannot achieve this.

Comment: For example here is a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/7ScyKAbnzdYWzs16S9Ax?p=preview of me using ng-if/ng-style to change the height of a div based on a selected tab, I tried to use a similar setup using visibility:hidden but the main difference between the two situations is I was changing the style of one div. The issue with my current situation is I need to show/hide 4 different iframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your plunk and found that you forgot `ng-app`.

Then, create a function inside your controller to show/hide videos

```
var app = angular.module('ngApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.currentVideo = 1;
  $scope.setCurrentVideo = function(videoNumber) {
      $scope.currentVideo = videoNumber;
  };
});
```

And modify html markup to be like

```
<!-- IFRAMES -->
<iframe class="..." src="..." style="..." ng-show="currentVideo === 1"></iframe>

<iframe class="..." src="..." style="..." ng-show="currentVideo === 2"></iframe>

<iframe class="..." src="..." style="..." ng-show="currentVideo === 3"></iframe>

<iframe class="..." src="..." style="..." ng-show="currentVideo === 4"></iframe>

<!-- BUTTONS -->
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h4>1st Video (initial video)</h4>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/140x150" ng-click="setCurrentVideo(1);"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h4>2nd Video</h4>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/140x150"  ng-click="setCurrentVideo(2);"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h4>3rd video</h4>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/140x150"  ng-click="setCurrentVideo(3);"/>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <h4>4th video</h4>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/140x150"  ng-click="setCurrentVideo(4);"/>
</div>
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mG4qhKb162alwSfB9lI4?p=preview).